# Adding two labels on a form bootstrap while aligning columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I am attempting to align a form per my UI/UX specs to look like this with a parent label on a form and then two sub-labels. Is this possible with Bootstrap?

[image: Form with two labels]

But I'm having a hard time aligning my columns are rows. Is this even possible? Or are these those nested forms that aren't allowed? Here is my markup along with a link to a fiddle.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Parent Label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label">Sub Label 1</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" value="Dynamically Pulled via Razor">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label">Sub Label 2</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" value="Dynamically Pulled via Razor">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xue2vfde/

Comment: I've got it looking like this now! https://jsfiddle.net/xue2vfde/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wan't doing a good job aligning my columns, on the input fields. After I wrapped the inputs in a column div, I was good to go!

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Parent Label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sub Label 1</label>
        <div class = "col-sm-6">
                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" value="Dynamically Pulled via Razor">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sub Label 2</label>
        <div class = "col-sm-6">
                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" value="Dynamically Pulled via Razor">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xue2vfde/4/